# similar functionality to SQL Server's EXCEPT operand in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, syntax, comparison

Is there an operand/function/command in MySQL similar to the [`EXCEPT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) operand in SQL Server?

`EXCEPT` returns any distinct values from the left query that are not also found on the right query.

This statement should give me the distinct values.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM table2;
```

How can this be achieved in MySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best you could do is use a `NOT EXISTS`. Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM table1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                         FROM table2
                         WHERE table1.x = table2.x)
```

Comment: Agreed. Suspect the WHERE clause need to check equality on each column of t1 and t2?

Comment: @p. campbell: Correct. I should have been clearer about that.