# Sqlzoo using EXCEPT

Tags: mysql, except

The table has three columns: year, winner, subject.
The question is: In which years was the Physics prize awarded but no Chemistry prize.
I tried the following code and got an syntax error.
Any help will be appreciated!

```
SELECT DISTINCT yr
FROM nobel WHERE subject = 'Physics'

EXCEPT

SELECT DISTINCT yr
FROM nobel WHERE subject = 'Chemistry'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405729/mysql-query-to-select-everything-except

Answer (score 0):

I think that exact code should work if you use NOT IN instead of EXCEPT. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682084/similar-functionality-to-sql-servers-except-operand-in-mysql) implies that MySQL doesn't support EXCEPT - perhaps that is the problem?

To confirm this you can scroll up to the top of the SQL Zoo page and change the engine to "SQL Server" - that makes your exact query work for me.